How can I edit this code so that I can insert my own sinogram for image reconstruction?
I have an image that I'm turning into a sinogram to then backproject, but I want to edit this code so that I'm inserting my own sinogram instead (so the true object is unknown).
    from skimage.data import brain
    from skimage.transform import resize, rescale
    from numba import jit, cuda
    import cuda

    import numpy as np
    import torch, torch.nn as nn
    import cv2

    def cv2disp(win, ima, xp, yp, sc): cv2.imshow(win, rescale(ima, sc, False) *1.0/(np.max(ima)+1e-15)), cv2.moveWindow(win, xp, yp)
    def np_to_00torch(np_array):   return torch.from_numpy(np_array).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
    def torch_to_np(torch_array):  return np.squeeze(torch_array.detach().cpu().numpy())
    device  = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"); print(device)


    nxd = 128; disp_scale = 3
    nrd = int(nxd * 1.42); nphi = int(nxd* 1.42)

    brainimage=brain()
    true_object_np      = resize(brainimage[9,30:-1, :-30], (nxd,nxd), anti_aliasing=False)
    true_object_torch   = np_to_00torch(true_object_np).to(device)
    true_object_torch   = true_object_torch.float()


    cv2disp("True", true_object_np, 0, 0, disp_scale)




    #--------------------------------------Torch System Matrix----------------------------------------------
    def make_torch_system_matrix(nxd, nrd, nphi):
        system_matrix = torch.zeros(nrd*nphi, nxd*nxd) # rows = num sino bins, cols = num image pixels
        for xv in range(nxd):
            for yv in range(nxd):
                for ph in range(nphi):
                    yp = -(xv-(nxd*0.5)) * np.sin(ph*np.pi/nphi)+(yv-(nxd*0.5)) * np.cos(ph*np.pi/nphi)
                    yp_bin=int(yp+nrd/2)
                    system_matrix[yp_bin + ph*nrd, xv + yv*nxd] = 1.0
        return system_matrix


     def fp_system_torch(image, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi):
         fp =  torch.reshape(image, (nxd*nxd,1))
         fb = torch.mm(sys_mat, fp)
         return torch.reshape(fb, (nphi, nrd))
    def bp_system_torch(sino, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi):
    return torch.reshape(torch.mm(sys_mat.T, torch.reshape(sino, (nrd*nphi,1))), (nxd,nxd))



    sys_mat  = make_torch_system_matrix(nxd, nrd, nphi).to(device)


    true_sinogram_torch  = fp_system_torch(true_object_torch, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)


    cv2disp("Sinogram", torch_to_np(true_sinogram_torch), disp_scale*nxd, 0, disp_scale)



    #------------------------------------------End FP---------------------------------------------------


    #######################################CNN##########################################################

    class CNN(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, num_channels):
            super(CNN, self).__init__()
            self.CNN = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(1, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
                nn.Conv2d(num_channels, 1, 3, padding=(1, 1), padding_mode='reflect'), nn.PReLU(),
        )
        def forward(self,x):
            x = torch.squeeze(self.CNN(x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)))
            return x

    cnn = CNN(32).to(device)

    #######################################################################################################################


    #-------------------------------------------FBP------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class FBP_CNN_Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, cnn, sino_for_reconstruction):
            super(FBP_CNN_Net, self).__init__()
            self.sino_ones = torch.ones_like(sino_for_reconstruction)
            self.sens_image = bp_system_torch(self.sino_ones, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)
            self.cnn = cnn
            self.prelu = nn.PReLU()

        def forward(self, sino_for_reconstruction):
            filtered_sino = self.cnn(sino_for_reconstruction)
            recon = bp_system_torch(filtered_sino, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi) / (self.sens_image+1.0e-15)
            recon = self.prelu(recon)
            fpsino = fp_system_torch(recon, sys_mat, nxd, nrd, nphi)


            cv2disp("Filtered Sino", torch_to_np(filtered_sino), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd), 0, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("FBP", torch_to_np(recon), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd), disp_scale*nphi+30, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("FP Sino", torch_to_np(fpsino), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd+nphi), 0, disp_scale)
            cv2disp("Difference", torch_to_np(fpsino - sino_for_reconstruction), disp_scale*(nxd+nrd+nrd), disp_scale, sc= 0)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            return recon, fpsino

    fbpnet = FBP_CNN_Net(cnn, true_sinogram_torch).to(device)

#===========================================TRAINING OF THE NETWORK

    loss_fun = nn.MSELoss()
    optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(fbpnet.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)

    train_loss = list()
    epochs = 6000

    for ep in range(epochs):
        fbp_recon, rec_fp = fbpnet(true_sinogram_torch)
        loss = loss_fun(rec_fp, torch.squeeze(true_sinogram_torch))
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        print('Epoch %d Training loss = %f' % ( ep, train_loss[-1]))



I'd like to not know what the true image is and just insert a sinogram and run it, but I'm not quite sure how to do that (especially regarding the dimensions the image should be mapped to).
